# VBA Macro for creating combinations

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro for the below mentioned situation.

*The input is:*

```
Col A   Col B
A       B
A       C
B       D
C       A
C       B
C       E
D       A
D       B
E       A
```

I am trying to make combinations such as 
*Output:*

```
A   B   D   A       
A   C   A           
A   C   B   D   A   
A   C   E   A       
B   D   B           
C   A   B   D   A   C
C   A   C           
C   B   D   A   C   
C   E   A   C

|
|
|
```

and so on

The output can be on the same worksheet.

The output should have the starting point and ending point as the same.
The loop should start with first row and look for combinations in such a way that the starting point and ending point is the same.

I am simply unable to figure out, how to create a loop like this.

Please suggest some ideas.

Comment: I think you'll need to edit your question, and try again to describe what you want. Based on your description, I'd expect the first output line to be "ABCA", because it starts with "A" and ends with the first occurrence of "A" in the second column. But that's not what you expect.

Comment: I apologize for not mentioning that, but the output is basically a loop. So for first row the algorithm should take the value from col B i.e. "B" and look for "B" in col A. If Col A has "B" then it should check if the "B" has value "A"(colB) or not. If yes then it should constitue as on loop and should be in the output. If not then it will take the Value next to "B" i.e. "D"(in this scenario) and look for "D" in Col A. If "D" is in Col A then it should look for "A" next to D. If there is "A" then the loop is complete. I hope this makes sense. I know it's confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directed graphs, avoiding cycles and recursion. Beautiful challenge.
Code need a lot of improvements but is 1 am and I had to install Excel at home :/

I have assumed that you data are in range A1:B9. Solution is printed in Immediate Window( work of format by your self).

```
Option Explicit

Sub EveningFun()

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rRng As Range

    Dim goal As String

    Dim availablePaths(1 To 9) As Boolean

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 9
        availablePaths(i) = True
    Next i


    Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A9")

    For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
        goal = rCell.value

        Call RecursiveFun(goal, rCell.Offset(0, 1).value, goal, availablePaths)

    Next rCell

End Sub

Sub RecursiveFun(goal As String, nextElement As String, path As String, availablePaths() As Boolean)

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rRng As Range

    Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A9")

    For Each rCell In rRng.Cells

        If goal = nextElement Then
            'Debug.Print path & nextElement
             Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Cells.Offset(1, 0) = path & nextElement
             Exit Sub
        End If

        If nextElement = rCell.value And availablePaths(rCell.Row) Then
            Dim onePathLess(1 To 9) As Boolean
            Call CopyArrays(availablePaths(), onePathLess())
            'some key place, we have to avoid cycles
            onePathLess(rCell.Row) = False

            Call RecursiveFun(goal, rCell.Offset(0, 1).value, path & nextElement, onePathLess())
        End If

    Next rCell

End Sub

Sub CopyArrays(source() As Boolean, target() As Boolean)

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 9
        target(i) = source(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

+4 for very great task but -3 for not trying.

Comment: ;] . I hope you find above useful. GL!

Comment: Thank You So Much ! That really helps. I now have something good to start with. I added the macro but it doesn't give me any output nor any results. But I am working on it and will give you some feedback asap. I pologize for not writing my code in the first place. Actually I am new to Macro and I didnt wanted to confuse the audience.

Comment: So fast tutorial. Go to the VBA editor *alt+f11". Turn on Immediate Window "ctrl+G". Go to code in Sheet1. Click into the body of function EveningFun(). Press F5. Tadam!

Comment: Thanks..  I know how to run a macro, but in this scenario when I run it, I don't get any errors or results. Is there a way I can post the test file here ?

Comment: Here is my output: abda
aca
acbda
acea
bdab
bdacab
bdacb
bdaceab
bdb
cabdac
cac
cbdac
ceabdac
ceac
dabd
dacabd
dacbd
daceabd
eabdace
eace
dbd. Have you filed cells from A1 to B9?

Comment: Yes i did filled it from A1 to B9, but I am not sure why the result is not appearing anywhere on the file. In which cells are you getting your results ?

Comment: This is how I run the macro. Developer Tab --> View Code --> Click into the body of function EveningFun() --> Press F5

Comment: Did you turn on Immediate Window "ctrl+G"? Find Debug.Print in Google.

Comment: I did turned on the immediate window but nothing happened. I am not sure why we need to do that in order to run the macro. I am sorry but I am new to this. Usually whenever I create a new macro, I just go to the developer tab and run the code and usually print the results in a new worksheet or a new workbook.  Did you got the output in Sheet 1 ?

Comment: i got this result : CBDAC
CEABDAC
CEAC
DABD
DACABD
DACBD
DACEABD
DBD
EABDACE
EACE
ABDA
ACA
ACBDA
ACEA
BDAB
BDACAB
BDACB
BDACEAB
BDB
CABDAC
CAC
CBDAC
CEABDAC
CEAC
DABD
DACABD
DACBD
DACEABD
DBD
EABDACE
EACE
ABDA
ACA
ACBDA
ACEA
BDAB
BDACAB
BDACB
BDACEAB
BDB
CABDAC
CAC
CBDAC
CEABDAC
CEAC
DABD
DACABD
DACBD
DACEABD
DBD
EABDACE
EACE
ABDA
ACA
ACBDA
ACEA
BDAB
BDACAB
BDACB
BDACEAB
BDB
CABDAC
CAC
CBDAC
CEABDAC
CEAC
DABD
DACABD
DACBD
DACEABD
DBD
EABDACE
EACE
ABDA
ACA
ACBDA
ACEA
BDAB
BDACAB
.....................

Comment: I know what you werte refering to now. Actually I was expecting the results in the sheet so got confused. Thanks for your help. I appreciate that.

Comment: One last Question : If possible please explain this code.          Sub CopyArrays(source() As Boolean, target() As Boolean)

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 9
        target(i) = source(i)
    Next i

End Sub
---------- The reason I am asking is because the present scenario I gave you has 9 rows, but I have scnarios where the no. of rows are 500. In that scenario, do I need to change this For Loop to : For i= 1 to 500 ?

Comment: Another thing that I noticed was that on the output window, I can see only 199 results. SO if I change the Copy Arrays loop from 9 to 100 or 200...everytime I get different results but on the output screen there are only 199 results. Is there any other way I can print the entrie result ? I know this needs improvement and first of all I am trying to understand the way this is working because I am a beginner.Thanks. Appreciate your help.

Comment: This is your own task, you have to figure it out how replace 'Debug.Print path & nextElement' by something else. Maybe print it to some sheet, or to a file. I am keeping fingers crossed ;]

Comment: Hi Guys....I need help with this. I am not able to get the output of this macro in a spreadsheet. If the number of columns are above 100, I can see the result when the macro runs but on the debug screen(Ctrl+G) the results is partial. So I think it would be better to have this result on a new worksheet. Please advice.

Comment: You got it Bro ! Please bear with me . I am new to Macro and you have to be my Guru :)

Comment: Wawrzyniec: Need your help on one more the change. Presently this code will create loops for any no. of nodes. Is there a way we can restrict that. For example I don't want my solution to have more than 5 nodes including the 1st and last being the same. So from all the paths mentioned in the solution, path C   A   B   D   A   C
should not be considered. Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: LOL Man I did your job now you are trying other to make same in Java. Have you considered to work on your own?

Comment: I am new to programming and will catch up soon and I am working on my own. BTW, the intent for Java is to find the correct algorithm and not the code because what I am doing won't be limited to macro. You have been fo great help but this problem has way more constraints then creating paths. FYI, the code mentioned above doesn't work for more than 100 nodes. I am trying to understand that and fix it. I will surely put an updated macro asap. Just a matter of time.