# How to list all possible combinatios of the values in SIX columns in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, combinations

I have this challenge.

I have six columns, each of which has different kinds of master data as shown below:

[image: Table]

Now, I want to have all possible combinations of these six cells - like (and so on)

[image: Results]

Im trying to take this with the formula shown below:

```
=IF.ERROR(INDEX($A:$A,IF(INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/(((COUNTA(B:B)-1)*(COUNTA(C:C)-1)*(COUNTA(D:D)-1)*(COUNTA(E:E)-1)*(COUNTA(F:F)-1))))+2>COUNTA(A:A),-1,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/(((COUNTA(B:B)-1)*(COUNTA(C:C)-1)*(COUNTA(D:D)-1)*(COUNTA(E:E)-1)*(COUNTA(F:F)-1))))+2))&" "INDEX(B:B,MOD(INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/(COUNTA(C:C)-1)),(COUNTA(B:B)-1))+2)&" "INDEX(C:C,MOD(INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/(COUNTA(D:D)-1)),(COUNTA(C:C)-1))+2)&" "INDEX(D:D,MOD(INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/(COUNTA(E:E)-1)),(COUNTA(D:D)-1))+2)&" "INDEX(E:E,MOD(INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/(COUNTA(F:F)-1)),(COUNTA(E:E)-1))+2)&" "INDEX(F:F,MOD((ROW(1:1)-1),(COUNTA(F:F)-1))+2," ")
```

I'm applying to each position (a,b,c,d,e,f) to achieve the variation of each one in the last position as you will see in the next image.

[image: Sheet in Excel]

My excel it is in Spanish, so the formula it's an adaptation of the formula shown in: [How to list all possible combinations of the values in three columns in excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48651400/how-to-list-all-possible-combinations-of-the-values-in-three-columns-in-excel)

I don't know if I am doing well because this formula is giving me a lot of duplicates without sense and I'm not able to verify if this formula is covering ALL possible combinations.

I really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Use VBA,  It will be cleaner and quicker.

Comment: Instead of posting a picture of your code/formula your should copy it into the question so others can try it without having to transcribe.

Comment: Have a look at and edit this to your situation : https://stackoverflow.com/q/15138184/4961700